# ssh: Could not resolve hostname (updating hostname for machine on local LAN)

Tags: lan, linux, ssh

I have connected a raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 20.04 to my local LAN over wifi.

From my laptop I can SSH to the raspberry just fine with:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.47
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1022-raspi aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
 ...
```

Instead of having to type that IP each time I would like to be able to SSH to it using the hostname: `rasp01`. I have found this guide:

https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/19668676-renaming-your-raspberry-pi-the-hostname

that I have followed. After I have rebooted the raspberry pi and logged into it I have this:

```
ubuntu@rasp01:~$ hostname
rasp01

ubuntu@rasp01:~$ cat /etc/hosts

rasp01 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

ubuntu@rasp01:~$ cat /etc/hostname 
rasp01
```

But when I try to use that hostname when I SSH to the raspberry from my laptop on the same LAN (also running ubuntu) I get:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@rasp01
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasp01: Name or service not known

$ ssh ubuntu@rasp01.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasp01.local: Name or service not known

$ ssh ubuntu@rasp01.local.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasp01.local.: Name or service not known
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately,  questions about host/server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

The [Super User](https://superuser.com/) section of Stack Exchange is focused on power users.  It's a good resource for SOHO networking questions such as yours.  This site is for network engineering professionals, so your question is actually not on-topic here.

However, there are several ways to do what you want, among them:

- Add an entry to `/etc/hosts` on your workstation mapping rasp01 to 192.168.0.47
- Configure your SSH `~/.ssh/config` file, adding a host entry
- Setup a DNS service for your home LAN, especially if your router supports integration with its DHCP server